# New cassandra node cannot be joined if a value in composite type column is dropped

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, bootstrapping, astyanax

I get a **RuntimeException** at new node system.log on bootstrapping a new DC.

**Is it a bug of Cassandra 2.0.9?**

Log System.out - RuntimeException caused by IllegalArgumentException in Buffer.limit:

```
INFO [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2014-08-26 15:43:01,030 SecondaryIndexManager.java (line 137) Submitting index build of [myColumnFamily.myColumnFamily_myColumn] for data in SSTableReader(path='/var/lib/cassandra/data/testbug/myColumnFamily/testbug-myColumnFamily-jb-1-Data.db')
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:2] 2014-08-26 15:43:01,035 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:2,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:587)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytesWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:596)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:61)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:36)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.LocalToken.compareTo(LocalToken.java:44)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findPredecessor(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findNode(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:789)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doGet(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:828)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.get(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1626)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.resolve(Memtable.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:173)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:900)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.insert(AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.indexRow(SecondaryIndexManager.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.indexRow(Keyspace.java:413)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexBuilder.build(SecondaryIndexBuilder.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$9.run(CompactionManager.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2014-08-26 15:43:01,035 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[NonPeriodicTasks:1,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:413)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.maybeBuildSecondaryIndexes(SecondaryIndexManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReceiveTask$OnCompletionRunnable.run(StreamReceiveTask.java:113)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:409)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:587)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytesWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:596)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:61)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:36)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.LocalToken.compareTo(LocalToken.java:44)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findPredecessor(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findNode(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:789)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doGet(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:828)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.get(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1626)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.resolve(Memtable.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:173)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:900)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.insert(AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.indexRow(SecondaryIndexManager.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.indexRow(Keyspace.java:413)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexBuilder.build(SecondaryIndexBuilder.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$9.run(CompactionManager.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    ... 3 more
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:2] 2014-08-26 15:43:01,036 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:2,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:587)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytesWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:596)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:61)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.compare(AbstractCompositeType.java:36)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.LocalToken.compareTo(LocalToken.java:44)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DecoratedKey.compareTo(DecoratedKey.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findPredecessor(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:727)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findNode(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:789)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.doGet(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:828)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.get(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:1626)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.resolve(Memtable.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:173)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:900)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.insert(AbstractSimplePerColumnSecondaryIndex.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.indexRow(SecondaryIndexManager.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.indexRow(Keyspace.java:413)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexBuilder.build(SecondaryIndexBuilder.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$9.run(CompactionManager.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My steps to reproduce (Сassandra 2.0.9):

1. In one node datacenter DC1 create a keyspace with NetworkTopologyStrategy, options DC1=1, DC2=1.
2. Create a CF with a secondary index on a CompositeType(Int32Type, UUIDType).
3. Write any composite value to a row.
4. Drop the value.
5. Write another composite value to another row.
6. Drop second value.
7. Bootstrap add a new node in DC2.
8. DC2 gets an exception.

The similar issue I got  on indexed composite column in a single 3 nodes DC with SimpleStrategy and replication_factor=3 (cassandra 1.2.18).

I use Astyanax 2.0.1 (I tested on Astyanax 1.56.49 as well), here is the code that generates keyspace (steps 1-6) that fails on a new datacenter node bootstrap.
Source CassandraBugTest.java:

```
package test;

import com.netflix.astyanax.AstyanaxContext;
import com.netflix.astyanax.Cluster;
import com.netflix.astyanax.Keyspace;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.NodeDiscoveryType;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.ConnectionException;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolType;
import com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl;
import com.netflix.astyanax.ddl.ColumnDefinition;
import com.netflix.astyanax.ddl.ColumnFamilyDefinition;
import com.netflix.astyanax.ddl.KeyspaceDefinition;
import com.netflix.astyanax.impl.AstyanaxConfigurationImpl;
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.ColumnFamily;
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.Composite;
import com.netflix.astyanax.model.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.*;
import com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftFamilyFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class CassandraBugTest
{
    private static final String SEEDS = "dc1n1";
    private static final String CLUSTER_NAME = "Test Cluster";
    private static final String KEYSPACE_NAME = "testbug";
    private static final String COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME = "myColumnFamily";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "myColumn";

    @Test
    public void test() throws ConnectionException, InterruptedException
    {
        AstyanaxContext.Builder builder = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
                .forCluster(CLUSTER_NAME)
                .forKeyspace(KEYSPACE_NAME)
                .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl()
                                .setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.RING_DESCRIBE)
                                .setConnectionPoolType(ConnectionPoolType.TOKEN_AWARE)
                                .setCqlVersion("3.1.7")
                                .setTargetCassandraVersion("2.0.9")
                                .setDefaultWriteConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_LOCAL_QUORUM)
                                .setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.CL_LOCAL_QUORUM)
                )
                .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("TaxiClusterConnectionPool")
                                .setInitConnsPerHost(1)
                                .setMaxConnsPerHost(8)
                                .setSeeds(SEEDS)
                )
                .withConnectionPoolMonitor(new Slf4jConnectionPoolMonitorImpl());

        AstyanaxContext<Cluster> clusterContext = builder.buildCluster(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
        clusterContext.start();
        Cluster cluster = clusterContext.getClient();

        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put("DC1", "1");
        options.put("DC2", "1");

        KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDef = cluster.makeKeyspaceDefinition()
                                                .setName(KEYSPACE_NAME)
                                                .setStrategyClass("NetworkTopologyStrategy")
                                                .setStrategyOptions(options);

        try
        {
            cluster.dropKeyspace(KEYSPACE_NAME);
        }
        catch (BadRequestException e)
        {
        }

        cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDef);

        ColumnFamily<UUID, String> profiles = new ColumnFamily<>(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME, UUIDSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());

        ColumnFamilyDefinition columnFamilyDef = cluster.makeColumnFamilyDefinition()
                                                        .setName(profiles.getName())
                                                        .setKeyspace(KEYSPACE_NAME)
                                                        .setKeyValidationClass(profiles.getKeySerializer().getComparatorType().getTypeName())
                                                        .setComparatorType(profiles.getColumnSerializer().getComparatorType().getTypeName());

        ColumnDefinition columnDef = cluster.makeColumnDefinition()
                                            .setValidationClass(
                                                    ComparatorType.COMPOSITETYPE.getTypeName() +
                                                    "(" + ComparatorType.INT32TYPE.getTypeName() +
                                                    "," + ComparatorType.UUIDTYPE.getTypeName() +
                                                    ")"
                                            )
//                                             Use BYTESTYPE here for validation class for workaround, then no bug occurs.
//                                            .setValidationClass(ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE.getTypeName())
                                            .setName(COLUMN_NAME)
                                            .setIndex(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME + "_" + COLUMN_NAME, "KEYS");

        columnFamilyDef.addColumnDefinition(columnDef);

        cluster.addColumnFamily(columnFamilyDef);

        AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> keyspaceContext = builder.buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());
        keyspaceContext.start();
        Keyspace keyspace = keyspaceContext.getClient();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
            Composite value = new Composite();
            value.addComponent(1, IntegerSerializer.get());
            value.addComponent(UUID.randomUUID(), UUIDSerializer.get());
            value.setSerializersByPosition(IntegerSerializer.get(), UUIDSerializer.get());

            keyspace.prepareColumnMutation(profiles, id, COLUMN_NAME)
                    .putValue(value, CompositeSerializer.get(), null)
                    .execute();

            keyspace.prepareColumnMutation(profiles, id, COLUMN_NAME)
                    .deleteColumn()
                    .execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I found that it works if I use BytesType validation class for the column (aka blob). But still no way to have it working with CompositeType.